# Logical AND between elementwise and rowwise conditions in pandas (bolean and between matrix and column)

Tags: python, pandas

Editted:
How does one combine logical masks of different sizes in pandas?
For example, find all elements that satisfy an elementwise condition while the row they are in also satisfies another condition.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name':'x y T Bob Banana'.split(),'value':[-100, 0, -1, 100, -33],'value_too':[1,2,2,2,-11]})
name value  value_too
x     -100          1
y        0          2
T       -1          2
Bob    -33          2
Banana   0        -11
```

Imagine if in a table above I need to change the negative values in the rows with `T`,`Bob`,`Banana`.
Checking the name gives a series of size 5:

```
c1 = df.name.isin({'Banana','Bob','T'})
```

Checking if a value is a negative numer gives a dataframe 5 by 3:

```
c2 = df.applymap(lambda x: x < 0 if isinstance(x,(int,float)) else False)
```

In matlab doing a binary operation on a vector of size m and matrix of size (m,n) would translate the operation across n columns and the result would also be of size (m,n). In python `c1 & c2` produces a 5 by 8 table filled with `False`.

How are conditions of this type combined into a 5 by 3 matrix that can be fed into `df.where` `cond`? (In the table above it should point to values -1,-33 and -11.)

```
mask = ?????(c1,c2)
df = df.where(mask,0)
```

dtypes of the data are irrelevant, in the real problem all entries are strings, but numbers make example simpler.

---

Original text below.

Suppose I have pandas dataframe:

```
 df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3],'b':[1,3,5]})
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  3
2  3  5
```

I can get a boolean mask by value to find elements of particular value:

```
q = df >1
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  1  1
```

I can get a boolean vector to find rows where column satisfies a condition:

```
q.b == 3
0
1
0
```

What is the idiomatic way of finding elements that satisfy a combination of these conditions?

```
??????     
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  0    
edit: actually the expected output was
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
(value greater than 1 and in a row that has b == 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled with explicit combining of the column.
This selects elements that satisfy `c2` and are in a row that satisfies `c1`:

```
pad = c2.apply(lambda x: x&c1)
#size (5,3)
```

This selects rows which satisfy `c1` or contain element satisfying `c2`:

```
pad2 = c2.agg(any,axis = 1) | c1
#size (5,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try via `assign()` method:

```
out=df.gt(1).astype(int).assign(b=df['b'].eq(3).astype(int))
```

output of `out`:

```
    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   1
2   1   0
```

**OR**

via `where()` method

```
out=df.gt(1).astype(int).where(df['b']==3,0)
```

Output of `out`:

```
    a   b
0   0   0
1   0   1
2   0   0
```

**Note:** *choose any 1 of the above method as per your need*

If needed in form of `True/False` then use:

```
d={0:False,1:True}
out=out.replace(d.keys(),d.values(),regex=True)
```

Comment: Maybe change the df  to pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,3],'b':[1,3,5]})

Comment: @BENY Thanks Sir for noticing...updated answer **:)**

Comment: looks better now ~ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your first `gt` condition seems like not necessary

```
df[['b']].eq(3).reindex(df.columns,axis=1,fill_value=False)
Out[111]: 
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False   True
2  False  False
```